Advice needed on how to connect a 12V solenoid valve to a Raspberry Pi
I'm a begineer to using the Pi and want to build a simple watering system for some plants. I know there's lots of online articles but looking for some clarification on exactly what is needed. Here's the situation:
I've got a Pi Model B and a 12V solenoid valve, similar to https://thepihut.com/products/plastic-water-solenoid-valve-12v-1-2-nominal.
I've also got a small soil sensor that is successfully reading the moisture level of the plant soil. To achieve this the sensor is being powered by connecting the appropriate pins from the Pi (so I've used the Pi's 5V power pin, ground pin and another pin to get the reading) after looking at https://pinout.xyz/.
I'm looking for some help in understanding:

how can I power the solenoid valve (I'd like to buy a 12V power supply that plugs into the mains)?
how do you actually connect that power supply to the valve?
having got power for the valve, what other parts do you need to connect it to the Pi? I'm thinking of wires, boards etc

I guess what I need is the shopping list of the bits needed to allow the valve to be powered and connected to the Pi.
Thanks for any help!

research how to control a solenoid with a microcontroller ... your question is not specific to the Raspberry Pi

Once you have worked out WHAT you are going to connect ask a question about interfacing to the Pi.

Did you not read the rules stating questions Asking for specific purchasing recommendations are off-topic here? We'd like to help, but you've gotta' do your part!

In your case, I would use a USB relais card and use usbrelay to switch. Together with a fairly common, cheap 12V power supply, you should be able to get this working.
